# SSH logging to MySQL Database parallel to auth.log

Tags: mysql, ssh, logging

As the title says, is there any way to force sshd logging (of authentication failures) to a MySQL table in addition to the /var/log/auth.log file ?

*My Server is Debian Squeeze, openssh, mysql5, 2.6.32-028stab094.3 #1 SMP Thu Sep 22 12:47:37 MSD 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe OpenSSH Server supports this directly, but it's quite simple to configure [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog_mysql.html) or [syslog-ng](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Syslog-ng_directly_to_MySQL) to insert logs into a MySQL table.

Comment: "I don't believe ... supports" is not very accurate but neither is "I think you are right", thank you, I should replace my syslog by rsyslog or something.